# How can I download and upload a file at the same time?

Tags: php, curl, wget

Here's a thing- there is a file on external server.
My script needs to send the contents of this file to the visitor.
So it needs to download a file from the external server and then upload to the visitor. However the file is huge (>200 MB) so I cannot download file first then upload it- it would be too slow. And also I need to support resuming the download.
And that's the problem I am not sure how to handle properly.

One idea is:

1. start wget to download the file in background
2. then my script
       in PHP will send the contents of the file as it is being downloaded.
       But what if wget is slower then client's browser? Should my script
       wait?

Another one:

1. Use curl in PHP to download a file and on progress output what I downloaded. But then I am not sure how to handle resuming

I am not really sure how should I handle this situation.

Comment: you know what a proxy is?

Comment: @Dagon I do. You think I should write my own proxy or are there proxies I can configure that way?

Comment: i think this is way broad, but if you googled 'php proxy' you would probably find an answer

Comment: 200MB isn't that big for server-to-server transfer, so unless there is some real latency problem with the origin, it's most likely going to be a lot easier to handle it synchronously (i.e., download first). As mentioned it's pretty broad question and I imagine the specifics of an optimal solution would also depend on the file type. You may also explore some opportunistic strategy if you can predict which files are most likely to be requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that  one way can be to use two different sockets.  One of them that download the data and put the readed byte in a buffer where the other socket reads and send these data to the server where you want to upload the file.